# Using an activity instance which is not currently on the screen

Tags: android

I have an activity which is my main activity and launching in `singleInstance` mode. I am keeping a refence of main activity's instance in another class, so I am expecting the reach the instance of main activity in some other activities. But if I open another activity, I am not able change anything in main activity. Exception is below:

```
Exception when adding starting window

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2f18818 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:424)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:350)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.addStartingWindow(PhoneWindowManager.java:2359)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7840)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Is this not an allowed situation? How can make view changes in Activities which is not at the top of the stack?

Comment: you have to do your changes in onResume function of the main activity. save your parameters in second activity via sharepreferences or database and use them in onResume method of main acitivity

Comment: Holding onto references of Activity classes causes memory leaks, and there is probably a better way to do what you are trying to do

Comment: @JayakrishnanPm what a completely incorrect and horrible proposal

Comment: only make changes to the UI of an activity which is in resumed state with the help of a flag instead whole activity instance which stores the ui changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send messages or states information between activities, handler-message Model is suggested for you

Answer (score 0):

you should not update activity when they are invisible.
Instead, you should update activity in the `onResume()` callback, it is when the activity is going to be displayed to the user.
see more @ https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html